# IE attachment using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Is it possible to attach in an open internet explorer using selenium?
I've already read lots of forums about this, and they always said that it is possible for IE and not on other browsers. But the problem is, there is no available example or instruction on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Internet Explorer, but you can connect to an opened firefox browser if this browser instance is previously opened by WebDriver.

```
IWebDriver WebDriver = null;

try
{
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://localhost:7055/hub");
WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
Console.WriteLine("Executed on remote driver");

}

catch (Exception)
{

WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
Console.WriteLine("Executed on New FireFox driver");

}
```

see this blog post for more details
http://binaryclips.com/2014/09/16/selenium-web-driver-in-c-how-to-continue-script-on-the-already-opened-browser-instance/